# What new JS/HTML features is GitHub using?

Tags: github, safari, cross-browser

As of a couple days ago (let's say 2018-01-25), [GitHub](https://github.com) has started displaying a banner announcing that they have officially dropped support for "older versions of Safari" and recommending their visitors upgrade to Chrome or Firefox. I happen to still use Safari 9.1.2 (11601.7.7) on El Capitan (10.11.6).

I've found that usually when a website says "please upgrade your browser," Safari will still work anyway. However, with GitHub, it's different! I confirm that on El Capitan, many UI elements on the new GitHub site do not work at all. (But the site has not changed in appearance at all. The new UI elements look exactly like the old ones, but they no longer work in Safari.)

For a concrete example: On [the Pull Requests tab](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/compare), clicking on any of the three arrowed UI elements (such as "compare across forks") does nothing. Clicking on the other, un-arrowed, UI elements continues to work fine in Safari.

[[image: UI with arrows]]

Safari's Developer Console doesn't show any warnings or errors from the page, so whatever's going wrong, it's not apparent to Safari itself. I might guess the issue has to do with some new AJAX feature?

Anyway, the question is, what new JS/HTML features are being used by the new site in order to break compatibility with Safari/El Capitan? Where can I go to learn more about these new features, their functionality, and their adoption by various browsers?

Comment: To begin with, I would start looking at any errors in the browser console (press f12)